# Normalize a negative or positive number between -1 and 1?

Tags: c++, normalization

I have streaming data, as float values that range between -2 and +4. I need to write a function that normalizes these values between -1 and +1.

I have:

```
float normalize(float input)
{
    int min = -1;
    int max = 1;
    float normalized_x = (input - min) / (max - min);
    return normalized_x;
}
```

But this gives me values that are incorrect, and range from -0.4 to +2.3, roughly. What do I need to adjust in my function?

Thank you.

Comment: Aren't you surprised that values `-2` and `4` don't appear anywhere in your formula? The source range is kind of important, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: That is the range of the input data, so `float input`

Comment: @Igor you don't actually need those in particular. (Though you do need values derived form them)

Comment: @Iluvatar Well, maybe not directly, but at least some derivation of them. The current code doesn't acknowledge the source range in any shape of form. One can't really expect that the exact same calculation would magically fold [-2, 4] range and, say, [-100, 100] range equally well.

Comment: Why not using '<' and '>' operators? if( input < -1) return -1 ... ?

Comment: @alirakiyan That's a different operation entirely. You are thinking `clamp`, not `normalize`

Comment: Why not just map every value to 0? Or maybe there a *context* to tell us *how* and *why* a number in one range should be mapped to a particular other number in the other range?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to first center the range around 0, then divide to make it go from -1 to 1.

```
float normalize(float input)
{
    float normalized_x = (input - 1) / 3;
    return normalized_x;
}
```

More generalized:

```
const float min = -2;
const float max = 4;
float normalize(float input)
{
    float average      = (min + max) / 2;
    float range        = (max - min) / 2;
    float normalized_x = (input - average) / range;
    return normalized_x;
}
```